# I want to do the unit/auto test for extensions API of chromium/chrome, How should I do? use Jasmine?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to do the unit/auto test for extensions API of chromium/chrome, in order to verify the correctness of the extensions API interface.

Comment: please elaborate on the kind of testing you would like to do, is there a part of the Chrome API you are particularly interested in?

Comment: Now, I have solved it with QUnit.